# Why did my logins skip a tty?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I just logged into an Ubuntu server box with no X server.

I logged in 4 times concurrently with ssh:

```
$ last
user     pts/4        192.168.1.147    Mon May  1 11:19   still logged in
user     pts/3        192.168.1.147    Mon May  1 11:19   still logged in
user     pts/2        192.168.1.147    Mon May  1 11:18   still logged in
user     pts/0        192.168.1.147    Mon May  1 11:18   still logged in
```

Why did ssh server skip pts/1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a process already running which is using `/dev/pts/1`, including the possibility that `/dev/pts/1` might have been deleted, in which case shows up under `/proc/somePID/fd` as the symlink target `/dev/pts/1 (deleted)`. Once this process exits, the next time you ask for a terminal line this one will be reused.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that I have GNU screen installed and rtorrent running all the time in a screen session. I just looked at the output of 'ps -aux | grep pts' and pts 1 is being used by bash/rtorrent. So that is why it skips number 1 when logging in.